# Why content from some url's can't be loaded in AIR application?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I was trying to show Google Plus page for certain place in my AIR application using HTML control but HTML control displays page with error code 400. Same url can be opened in browser without any errors. I have also tried to load content using URLLoader and got same error 400. 
What can be different between browser and AIR? Is it possible that Goole can detect out of browser http requests and prevent them?

Comment: I searched the web about this, and it appears like this error might be caused by more than one browser instance trying to access the site. At least from within a browser, any AIR or Flash client is treated like a separate instance in terms of security, and I wouldn't be surprised if the same were true for an HTML viewer within an AIR application. There is a Google Plus API for AIR, though - perhaps you can implement your own interface and perform whatever functionality you desire. Or - but that's a long shot - perhaps there is a way to synchronize session ids before calling the site.

Comment: Thank you for helpfull comment, though it is weird that I can open same page in muliple browsers but can't open it in AIR. Unfortunately Google Plus API does not provide places information.

Comment: It is not so weird, because multiple browser windows also come with separate cookie- and session handling, while nested clients don't.

Answer (score 0):

The website may be blocking the following:

- Frame attempts
- Specific User Agents
- Unknown User Agents

**References**

- [Are you using a robots.txt File?](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/10/are_you_using_a.html)
- [Clickjacking Security Advisory](http://blogs.adobe.com/psirt/?p=24)